# correct way to use Unity onClick when the function needs an array parameter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    public int ArraySize = 100;
    private int[] array;

    void Start()
    {
        
        int[] array = Enumerable.Range(1, ArraySize).ToArray();

        ShuffleArray(array);
    }

    public void ShuffleArray(int[] array)
    {
         Random r = new Random();

         array = array.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToArray();

         VisualizeArray(array);
    }
```

i want to add the ShuffleArray method to a button in Unity, but unity doesnt allow multiple parameters for onClick, so im stumped, somehow i need to add a method that can read the array variable without being given it as a parameter?

ive tried removing the parameter but it just cant see the array value, and making methods to redirect but same issue or wont show in unity

Answer (score 0):

```
public Button ShuffleBtn;

void Start()
    {
        Button btn = ShuffleBtn.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(delegate { StartCoroutine(ShuffleArray(array)); });
    } 

IEnumerator ShuffleArray(int[] array)
    {
        // code
    }
```

this is how i ended up getting it working